# How make all assets of a HTML page update

Tags: html

I'm maintaining some static HTML/CSS websites, the problem is, when some images or stylesheets are changed. Some of the users still get the old version from cache served to them, Since we cannot manually instruct everybody to press ctrl+f5.

How can I instruct the browser that we have updated the pages to a new version, and to reload all resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to run a `.htaccess` file

Disable caching for certain file type

```
<FilesMatch ".(css|js|jpg|png)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
```

Or you could do this in HTML `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```